# Ruby on Rails: form_for is not showing content inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to create a form so I can update user's content information, but my form is not showing up.

My form in **views/admin/dashboard/index.html.erb**:

```
<% form_for @admin do |f| %>
  ... form content...
<% end %>
```

this is my controller in **controllers/admin/dashboard_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @admin = User.new
  end
end
```

this is my model: **models/admin.rb**

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then in my users model: **models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admins
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use output `<%=`

Instead of

```
<% form_for @admin do |f| %>
```

Use

```
<%= form_for @admin do |f| %>
```